# sparql filter won't work

Tags: filter, sparql, rdf, dbpedia

I want to get all players from a football club and filter those out that are from Germany, I know that it is possible without the filter option, but I'm new to SPARQL and it seems that i don't understand how to use the filter option in that case, so I would be glad if someone could tell a way how to get that working.

```
SELECT distinct ?player WHERE {
?player a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/SoccerPlayer>. 
?player <http://dbpedia.org/property/currentclub> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hertha_BSC>. 
optional {?subject <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace>/<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/country> ?<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Germany>. }
filter (!bound(?subject)).
} 
ORDER BY ASC(?player)
```

best regards Adrian

Comment: See my answer below. It's a duplicate, i.e. I will probably delete it but it's easier to describe things in an answer than in a comment. Please explain why you don't want to use the previous answer which does what you're asking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT distinct ?player WHERE {
    ?player a dbo:SoccerPlayer . 
    ?player dbp:currentclub dbr:Hertha_BSC . 
    ?player dbo:birthPlace/dbo:country? ?country .
    FILTER (?country = dbr:Germany)
    } 
ORDER BY ASC(?player)
```

Or this:

```
SELECT distinct ?player WHERE {
    ?player a dbo:SoccerPlayer . 
    ?player dbp:currentclub dbr:Hertha_BSC . 
    ?player dbo:birthPlace/dbo:country? ?country .
    FILTER (?country in (dbr:Germany))
    } 
ORDER BY ASC(?player)
```

Or even this:

```
SELECT distinct ?player WHERE {
    ?player a dbo:SoccerPlayer . 
    ?player dbp:currentclub ?club . 
    ?player dbo:birthPlace/dbo:country? ?country .
    VALUES (?club ?country) { (dbr:Hertha_BSC dbr:Germany) }
    } 
ORDER BY ASC(?player)
```

Comment: perfect that was exactly what i was looking for.